# c# wpf listview sort by colum with listviewitems

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

i try to sort a wpf Listview, this works fine .. but only if i add new Items as simple Objects:

this works:

```
listview_files.Items.Add(new { isdir = (String)ele.Element("isdir"), number = (int)ele.Element("id"), name = (String)ele.Element("name"), size = groesse, right = modes, date = (String)ele.Element("date") });
```

with:

```
listview_files.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, direction));
```

but if i add the items like this:

```
ListViewItem myitem = new ListViewItem();
            myitem.Content=new { isdir = (String)ele.Element("isdir"), number = (int)ele.Element("id"), name = (String)ele.Element("name"), size = groesse, right = modes, date = (String)ele.Element("date") };
            myitem.ContextMenu = con2;
            myitem.MouseDoubleClick += myitem_MouseDoubleClick;

         listview_files.Items.Add(myitem);
```

it will allways sort to the same, there is no difference between sortdirection or clicked colum (Values of sortBy, direction are allways correct)
I think the Problem is the "Content" Property, but how can i force the SortDescription to use the ListViewItem.Content Proberty for sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because the items collection' direct children are in the first case objects themselves and in the second - ListViewItem-s. So if you ask it to sort by `number` it won't find this property in a `ListViewItem`. It will, however, find `Content.number` and you may go with it. But why don't you use binding? It would be a more natural way to do it.

Comment: I meant data binding (using `ItemsSourse` property), so you won't need to create each individual ListViewItem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nadia, "Content."+sortBy works fine =) i tryed Databinding with Itemsource (generating a List with ListViewitems, but then other things didnt work anymore, for example the Doubleclikevent)